# How to edit Crystal Report "Show SQL Query"?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to modify "Show SQl Query" at crystal report. I had read many articles that tell (Report ->  Selection Formula -> Record) but i still can't find it.

This is the code from "Show SQL Query"

```
 SELECT `TestResult`.`LotNumber`, `TestResult`.`TestNo`, `TestResult`.`Test1Result`, `TestResult`.`Test2Result`, `TestResult`.`Test3Result`, `TestResult`.`Test4Result`, `TotalResult`.`TotalTested`, `TotalResult`.`TotalReject`, `ReportUse`.`Label1`, `ReportUse`.`Label2`, `ReportUse`.`Label3`, `ReportUse`.`Label4`, `TotalResult`.`ItemNumber`, `ReportUse`.`Parameter1a`, `ReportUse`.`Parameter1b`, `ReportUse`.`Parameter2`, `ReportUse`.`Parameter3`, `ReportUse`.`Parameter4`, `EEPROM`.`ProgrammerStation`, `TestResult`.`Eeprom`, `TestResult`.`FlowTest`, `TestResult`.`Remarks`, `TestResult`.`TNo`
 FROM   ((`ReportUse` `ReportUse` INNER JOIN `TotalResult` `TotalResult` ON `ReportUse`.`ItemNumber`=`TotalResult`.`ItemNumber`) INNER JOIN `TestResult` `TestResult` ON `TotalResult`.`LotNumber`=`TestResult`.`LotNumber`) INNER JOIN `EEPROM` `EEPROM` ON `TotalResult`.`ItemNumber`=`EEPROM`.`ItemNumber`
 ORDER BY `TestResult`.`TestNo`
```

I want to change this code to "ORDER BY Tno" instead of "ORDER BY `TestResult`.`TestNo`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You have to set required order from some CR menu (Report - Record sort expert on my old CR v11).

Comment: Thanks Arvo for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Report -> Selection Formula -> Record,
- expand Selection Formula,
- select Record Selection,
- then where condition query shows, you can edit it.

To edit select fileds:

- Go to View -> Field Explorer,
- drag and drop additional fields on the report, or remove fields from the report,
- save. It will automatically update the query.